# Carregar Busca Json em JSP

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp

Bom Dia
Estou tentando fazer este exemplo no meu projeto. 
É uma simples mudança de Select quando escolhe  Estado Muda as Cidades em outro Select.

https://gist.github.com/ografael/2037135

Mas não consigo buscar a variável, `estados_cidades.json` .

Tentei trazer como script
 `<script id="estados_cidades.json" src="GerenciaTI/Scripts/estados_cidades.json"  ></script>`

Mas ele não traz os dados pelo `Jquery`

Estou fazendo em paginas JSP, qual o erro que cometi ?

Ou se tiver uma maneira melhor de fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o exemplo funcionando...

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
  
   $.getJSON('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ografael/2037135/raw/5d31e7baaddd0d599b64c3ec04827fc244333447/estados_cidades.json', function (data) {
    var items = [];
    var options = '<option value="">escolha um estado</option>'; 
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
     options += '<option value="' + val.nome + '">' + val.nome + '</option>';
    });     
    $("#estados").html(options);    
    
    $("#estados").change(function () {    
    
     var options_cidades = '';
     var str = "";     
     
     $("#estados option:selected").each(function () {
      str += $(this).text();
     });
     
     $.each(data, function (key, val) {
      if(val.nome == str) {       
       $.each(val.cidades, function (key_city, val_city) {
        options_cidades += '<option value="' + val_city + '">' + val_city + '</option>';
       });       
      }
     });
     $("#cidades").html(options_cidades);
     
    }).change();  
   
   });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<body>

<form>
  
  <!-- Estado -->
  <select id="estados">
   <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <select id="cidades">
  </select>
 
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sim funcionou, mas ai você está puxando o link deles Online.

Comment: Mas e pra puxar Local ????

Comment: é so salvar o JSON localmente e puxa-lo, nao esta conseguindo fazer assim? vou montar um exemplo

Comment: isto, por favor

Comment: Aqui funcionou, voce pode colocar o link inteiro do arquivo salvo local. Ex: seu arquivo esta salvo dentro da pasta json. seria assim.

$.getJSON('http://localhost/MEUPROJETO/json/estados_cidades.json'

Comment: Ótimo, funcionou obrigado. Só uma última pergunta quanto á este código.  Pelo que intendi ele atribui o value dos estados certinho, estou puxando request.getParameter("estados")  e vem normalmente agora quando faço request.getParameter("cidades")  ele traz null na servlet ? o evento onchagen só muda o  value de estados

Comment: Se funcionou poderia marcar minha resposta? nesse caso, voce precisa fazer novamente a logica

Comment: eu sou muito lerdo mesmo ta tudo certo obrigado Rafael, eu que coloquei o nome errado na variavel kkkk